# Custom css author role

Tags: css, author, admin-css

I need a code snippet to load css (extra style sheet?) when a author is logged in. This is for a custom dashboard and post "page".

[image]

The screenshot is what i mean by post page. I want to hide stuf by css for only authors. Things within the red circles are things i want to hide.

Comment: Can you tell me what do you mean by "Custom dashboard"? Is it a WordPress page? Second thing is that what do you mean by post "page". Does it mean all the pages (post_type of 'page')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user is not logged in then [admin_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head) probably won't run. So let's just check their [capabilities](https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities).

```
function my_custom_admin_head() {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'have-fun' )) :
    ?><style>
        #welcome-panel{display: none !important;}
        #wp-content-editor-tools{display: none !important;}
    </style>
    <?php endif; // cant' have-fun
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_head' );
```

Comment: This is it! So i place my own css in the code and replace have-fun by administrator. Great! Always amazing how stange people help each other on these forums. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$url` according to your requirements. In the current state the `$url` links to a stylesheet `custom-style.css` located in your current active theme's subdirectory `admin`. I tested this code and it is working fine. Enjoy :-)

```
/**
 * This function registers and enqueues styles on front-end if
 * logged-in user has a role 'author'.
 */
function customStylesheetForAuthorsOnly() {

    /* Unique slug for the specific resource. */
    $handle = 'unique-css-stylesheet-handle';

    /* URL of the stylesheet (resource). */
    $url = get_template_directory_uri() . '/admin/custom-style.css';

    /* Array containing the handles of all the dependencies. */
    $dependencies = array();

    wp_register_style($handle, $url, $dependencies);

    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();

    /* Check if current user has 'author' in his roles */
    if(in_array('author', $current_user->roles) === true) {
        wp_enqueue_style($handle);
    }

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'customStylesheetForAuthorsOnly');
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look in to it. For now it breaks my site. I also posted a screenshot for more info. Thanks again.

Comment: @Arnolddew I've updated my answer.

Comment: You are right. This is the answer to my original Q. Thanks Omar.

Answer (score 0):

Get current user ID and compare it with post author ID. If they are equal then load extra style sheet.

To get current user ID use
`$user_ID = get_current_user_id();`

To get post author ID use
`$author_ID = get_the_author();`

The best practice to load style sheet is to use [wp_enqueue_style()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Css and html are not a problem to me. But coding is. Do you maybe have a sugestion for a snipet?

What about below, am i going in the right direction? 

`code`function wpdocs_enqueue_custom_admin_style() {
        wp_register_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/authorlayout.css', false, '1.0.0' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_wp_admin_css' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_enqueue_custom_admin_style' );`code`